# Printing object in Java

Tags: java, tostring

I ran the following code

```
String str = null;
System.out.println(str);
```

Output was **null**.

At first, I thought that the `NullPointerException` will be thrown as printing the object implicitly calls `toString` method. So, I was surprised with the output.

Then I contemplated about the output and thought that above String statement actually didn't create any object, only reference is created that doesn't point to any object. So that may be the reason of such output.

Can somebody please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `print()` methods [explicitly check](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28java.lang.String%29) for `null`.

```
public void print(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        s = "null";
    }
    write(s);
}
```

Comment: +1. See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 3):

[`PrintStream.print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) checks if it is `null`

```
 public void print(String s) {
   if (s == null) {
    s = "null";
   }
   write(s);
 }
```

From Javadoc [`PrintStream.print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) checks if it is `null`:

> Prints a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

Answer (score 2):

`NullPointerException` only occur when you use a reference pointing to `null` to invoke some method, or access some value. Merely printing a `null` value will not lead to a `NullPointerException`.

So, in the below code, you will get `NPE`: -

```
String str = null;
System.out.println(str.length());
```

If you see the source code of [`PrintStream#print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) method, it is as shown below: -

```
public void print(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        s = "null";
    }
    write(s);
}
```

So, it checks for `null` value and prints `"null"` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`Print()` checks for `null` by default, but when you do

```
System.out.print(str.toString());
```

now you'd get `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

Printing a object with `null` reference should not give you a problem. Calling an operation on `null` reference (or pointer, if you will) should give you a NPE.  Try doing a

`System.out.println (str.toString())`

and that should give you a nice NPE